# How do you calculate the cdf of a linear transformation of the normal distribution in python?

Tags: python, scipy, probability, normal-distribution, cdf

I have a pdf which is a linear transformation of the normal distribution:

```
T = 0.5A + 0.5B

Mean_A = 276

Standard Deviation_A = 6.5

Mean_B = 293

Standard Deviation_A = 6
```

How do I calculate the probability that T is between 281 and 291 in Python?

I have tried the following code:

```
mu1 = 276

sigma1 = 6.5

mu2 = 293

sigma2 = 6

normalized = 0.5 * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, loc = mu1, scale = sigma1) + 0.5 * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, loc = mu2, scale = sigma2)

print(normalized.cdf(291) - normalized.cdf(281))
```

But this came up with an error.

I've also tried to calculate the CDF of `T ~ N(284.5, 19.5625)` and

`print(norm.cdf(291 - 284.5/4.422952))`, etc but this came up with an incorrect answer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you assuming that the two normal random variates `A` and `B` are independent? In general the answer would depend on the covariance of the 2 random variables.

Comment: Maybe I'm incorrect in calling it a linear transformation, but we were basically given that the distribution follows the formula above, namely: 0.5 * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, loc = mu1, scale = sigma1) + 0.5 * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, loc = mu2, scale = sigma2). I've also tried calculating the probability using the  T ~ N where E(T) = 276(0.5)+ 293(0.5) and Var(T) = (0.5^2)(6.5^2) + (0.5^2)(6^2) and this was an incorrect answer also

Comment: Assuming independence, the latter approach is fine (cf. the answer below), but you can not operate on PDFs the way your pseudocode is suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment would suggest that you're assuming that the variables are independent, since in that case, the mean and the variance of the sum are given are as you've given.

Then, you can define the sum through

```py
normalized = scipy.stats.norm(0.5*mu1 + 0.5*mu2, np.sqrt((0.5*sigma1)**2 + (0.5*sigma2)**2))
```

and in particular, get your desired probably using `cdf` as you did:

```py
In [27]: normalized.cdf(291) - normalized.cdf(281)                                              
Out[27]: 0.7147892127602181
```

To validate that this result matches expectation, we can run a quick simulation:

```py
In [31]: N = 10**7                                                                               

In [32]: rvs = 0.5*np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, size=N) + 0.5*np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, size=N)     

In [33]: ((rvs > 281) & (rvs < 291)).mean()                                                              
Out[33]: 0.7148597
```

Indeed, this is a reasonable approximation to the exact result above.

**Edit**: As per the comment given to this answer, OP is actually interested in the random variable whose PDF is

> PX(x)=[1/(√2πVar1)^e^−(x−μ1)^2/2Var1]∗0.5+[1/(√2πVar2)^e^−(x−μ1)^2/2Var2]∗0.5

Notably, this is *not* a linear combination of normally distributed variables (and it's not itself a normally distributed variable for that matter), so if it's phrased as such in whichever exercise you're given, then they've worded it incorrectly.

This case is even simpler though: Integrating the PDF from 281 to 291 can be done by integrating each summand, which in turn is nothing but the PDF of a normal distribution, so that you can proceed as above:

```py
In [43]: n1 = scipy.stats.norm(mu1, sigma1)                                                                       

In [44]: n2 = scipy.stats.norm(mu2, sigma2)                                                                       

In [45]: .5*(n1.cdf(291) - n1.cdf(281) + n2.cdf(291) - n2.cdf(281))                                      
Out[45]: 0.2785306219161424
```

Comment: Both of these answers were marked as incorrect :(. I tried the second answer during my first go and that was marked incorrect as well. Specifically, the PDF given was PX(x)=[1/(√2πVar1)^e^−(x−μ1)^2/2Var1]∗0.5+[1/(√2πVar2)^e^−(x−μ1)^2/2Var2]∗0.5 ,μ1=276,σ1=6.5,μ2=293, σ2=6K. Sorry if that is hard to read but it looks like to me the normal Gaussian distribution times 0.5 two times. Not sure what i am doing incorrectly, thanks in advance!

Comment: Fair enough, but that's not 0.5A + 0.5B then. If you integrate that PDF, you just get the sum of the integrals for each individual Gaussian, so about 0.2785306219161424.

Comment: Thank you!! How do you do this in Python?

Comment: @b3llegsd I've updated the answer with this as well.

Comment: Great; if you found the answer useful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).